# MySQL - structure a query with different values that requires a lookup from the same table

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
 SELECT f.pending
      , f.title
      , f.funeraltype
      , f.firstname
      , f.middlename
      , f.lastname
      , f.suffix
      , f.displayage
      , f.age
      , f.displaycity
      , f.city
      , f.displaydate
      , f.date
      , f.aftersunset
      , f.funeraldate
      , f.displayfuneraldate
      , f.ftime
      , f.displayservicelocation
      , l.location
      , f.displaycemetery
      , c.name
      , f.displayobituary
      , f.obituary
      , f.displaycharity1
      , ch.name
      , f.charity1memo
      , f.displaycharity2
      , f.charity2
      , f.charity2memo
      , f.displaycharity3
      , f.charity3
      , f.charity3memo
      , f.displaycharity4
      , f.charity4
      , f.charity4memo
      , f.displaycharity5
      , f.charity5
      , f.charity5memo
      , f.memorialbook
      , f.displayshiva
      , f.displaytime
      , f.shivaendpart
      , f.shivauntil
      , f.shivaatresidence
      , f.shivaname
      , f.shivaaddress
      , f.shivacity
      , f.shivastate
      , f.shivazip
      , f.shivaphone
      , f.shivacomment
      , f.displayfamilymembers
      , f.familymembers
      , f.displayclergy
      , f.clergy
      , f.livevideo
      , f.archivevideo
      , f.video
      , f.usemp4video
      , f.mp4video
      , f.custom_text
      , f.charities_footnote
      , f.charity1note
      , f.charity2note
      , f.charity3note
      , f.charity4note
      , f.charity5note
   FROM funerals f
      , locations l
      , cemeteries c
      , charities ch
  WHERE f.servicelocation = l.locationid 
    AND f.cemetery = c.cemeteryID 
    AND f.charity1 = ch.CharityID 
    AND f.charity2 = ch.CharityID 
    AND f.charity3 = ch.CharityID 
    AND f.charity4 = ch.CharityID 
    AND f.charity5 = ch.CharityID
```

ch.name is what I'm looking to extract. f.charity1, f.charity2, f.charity3, f.charity4, & f.charity5 all contain different IDs that require a lookup in the 'charities' table.  How would I structure this query to display each charity name?

Comment: I would strongly suggest you consider drastically revising your schema design

Comment: Yes - that is why I need to get the data out of this db first.

Comment: So see about JOINs. Then JOIN the charity table to funerals 5 times, once for each charity, and remembering to give each instance of the joined table its own alias. We stopped using comma joins in about 1992, when they came to be effectively deprecated.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
    SELECT
      f.pending
      , f.title
      , f.funeraltype
      , f.firstname
      , f.middlename
      , f.lastname
      , f.suffix
      , f.displayage
      , f.age
      , f.displaycity
      , f.city
      , f.displaydate
      , f.date
      , f.aftersunset
      , f.funeraldate
      , f.displayfuneraldate
      , f.ftime
      , f.displayservicelocation
      , l.location
      , f.displaycemetery
      , c.name
      , f.displayobituary
      , f.obituary
      , f.displaycharity1
      , ch1.name
      , ch2.name
      , ch3.name
      , ch4.name
      , ch5.name
      , f.charity1memo
      , f.displaycharity2
      , f.charity2
      , f.charity2memo
      , f.displaycharity3
      , f.charity3
      , f.charity3memo
      , f.displaycharity4
      , f.charity4
      , f.charity4memo
      , f.displaycharity5
      , f.charity5
      , f.charity5memo
      , f.memorialbook
      , f.displayshiva
      , f.displaytime
      , f.shivaendpart
      , f.shivauntil
      , f.shivaatresidence
      , f.shivaname
      , f.shivaaddress
      , f.shivacity
      , f.shivastate
      , f.shivazip
      , f.shivaphone
      , f.shivacomment
      , f.displayfamilymembers
      , f.familymembers
      , f.displayclergy
      , f.clergy
      , f.livevideo
      , f.archivevideo
      , f.video
      , f.usemp4video
      , f.mp4video
      , f.custom_text
      , f.charities_footnote
      , f.charity1note
      , f.charity2note
      , f.charity3note
      , f.charity4note
      , f.charity5note
FROM funerals f
INNER JOIN  locations l on f.servicelocation = l.locationid 
INNER JOIN cemeteries c ON f.cemetery = c.cemeteryID 
INNER JOIN charities ch1 ON f.charity1 = ch1.CharityID
INNER JOIN charities ch2 ON f.charity2 = ch2.CharityID
INNER JOIN charities ch3 ON f.charity3 = ch3.CharityID
INNER JOIN charities ch4 ON f.charity4 = ch4.CharityID
INNER JOIN charities ch5 ON f.charity5 = ch5.CharityID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT f.pending
      , l.location
      , f.displaycemetery
      , c.name
      , f.displaycharity1
      , ch.name
      , f.charity1memo
      , f.displaycharity2
      , f.charity2
      , f.charity2memo
      , f.displaycharity3
      , f.charity3
      , f.charity3memo
      , f.displaycharity4
      , f.charity4
      , f.charity4memo
      , f.displaycharity5
      , f.charity5
      , f.charity5memo
      , f.charity1note
      , f.charity2note
      , f.charity3note
      , f.charity4note
      , f.charity5note
   FROM funerals f
   JOIN locations l
     ON l.locationid = f.servicelocation
   JOIN cemeteries c
     ON c.cemeteryID = f.cemetery   
   JOIN charities ch1
     ON ch1.CharityID = f.charity1
   JOIN charities ch2 
     ON ch2.CharityID = f.charity2 
    etc.
```